# Apache Lucene - Improving the results of Spell Checker

Tags: java, performance, apache, lucene, spell-checking

I recently implemented a SpellChecker using Apache Lucene. My code is provided below:

```
public void loadDictionary() {
    try {
        File dir = new File("c:/spellchecker/");
        Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(dir);
        spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
        Dictionary dictionary = new PlainTextDictionary(new File("c:/dictionary.txt"));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, null);
        spellChecker.indexDictionary(dictionary, config, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String performSpellCheck(String word) {
    try {
         String[] suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar(word, 1);
         if (suggestions.length > 0) {
             return suggestions[0];
         }
         else {
             return word; 
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

The above code uses a dictionary of English words. I am having a problem with the accuracy. What I want it to do is suggest similar words to words that are spelled incorrectly (that is, words that do not appear in the dictionary being used). However, if I send the word "post" to the performSpellCheck method, it returns "poet", that is, it is correcting words that do not need to be corrected (these words exist in the dictionary file).

Any suggestions on how I can improve my results?

Comment: I will rephrase your problem description. "I need to offer an alternative only if the word is in fact not a proper English word". Right now you look for a similar word unconditionally, so there seems to be something missing in your code. I wonder if the SpellChecker class has another method that might help... http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html

Answer (score 5):

I think, you should use [SpellChecker.exists()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html#exist%28java.lang.String%29) method. Use suggestSimilar method only if the word does not exists in the dictionary.