# How to get a spell corrected token from the 'binary file' in Apache OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, tokenize, opennlp

Apache NLP , Can I get the right token from the binary file.

If the input is "hosr road" which is typo error and correct word is "hosur road" ,
can I get the right word as "hosur road" as token after search in binary file.

```
    String input = "hosr road";
    InputStream tokenModelIn = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/nlp/en-token.bin");
    TokenizerModel tokenModel = new TokenizerModel(tokenModelIn);
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(tokenModel);
    String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize(input);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you can't.

The OpenNLP language models are not a dictionary to correct spelling in a given language. Moreover, "tokenization" is not the same as "spell correction". Tokens just represent the fragments of a sentence, so tokenization - as a natural language processing step - just gives you these fragments, even if they are misspelled. It won't correct those.

You could try another API/Framework for if you would like to have spell correction done with some text data. Maybe have a look at [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) and this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904931/apache-lucene-improving-the-results-of-spell-checker).